# Git - system is configured for two accounts, but git push is using the wrong account

Tags: git, github

When I try to use `git push origin RC-01`, I get an error:

> ERROR: Permission to user1/repo1.git denied to user2. fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

typing `git config -l` gives

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain 
core.repositoryformatversion=0 
core.filemode=true 
core.bare=false 
core.logallrefupdates=true 
core.ignorecase=true 
core.precomposeunicode=true 
remote.origin.url=git@github.com-personal:user1/repo1.git 
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
branch.master.remote=origin branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master 
user.name=user1 
user.email=user1@hotmail.co.uk
```

and `~/.ssh/config` has two entries:

```
# Work account (associates to user2)
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 User git
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work

# Personal account (associates to user1)
Host github.com-personal
 HostName github.com
 User git
 UseKeychain yes
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

when I do `ssh -T git@github.com-personal`,
I get

> Hi user2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

I cannot see how `user2` appears - it should be `user1` - I suspect this is my problem, but how do I get the push command to work?

Per suggestion from jingx, added `ssh -Tv git@github.com-personal` output:

```
$ ssh -Tv git@github.com-personal
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/named/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/named/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for github.com-personal
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/named/.ssh/id_rsa_personal type 0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/named/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.118.3]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi user2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `GIT_TRACE=true` and/or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'` to see how exactly git came up with user2?  You could also probably try `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh git@github.com-personal'` to force git to use user1.

Comment: Tried `ssh -v` it matched against a known-hosts entry for github.com, it shows a few interesting lines but they seem to confirm my config is ok, ie it is using `github.com-personal`. I've added the (edited) output above

Comment: Using `GIT_TRACE=true` gave this extra line: `18:04:25.960085 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com-personal' 'git-receive-pack '\''user1/repo1.git'\'''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ssh to connect to GitHub, the only *user name* that GitHub sees is `git`:

> ```
> ssh -T git@...
> ```

So GitHub needs some way to figure out who you are.

The way they use is to look at the *key you provide*.  You provided a key from:

> ```
> identity file /Users/named/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
> ```

They have a giant table, on their side, of keys and user-names.  They look through their key table and find the one that matches the key you just sent and it says: *This key is for user `user2`*.

So that's how GitHub knows that you are `user2`: *their* table says so.

To update their table, use their web interface.  Tell them: *You know me as user X (here's my credentials to prove it).  Now, my new key that you have never seen before is Y*.  They will add a *Y = X* entry to their giant table of every user in the universe.  Next time someone comes in claiming to be user `git` and providing key *Y*, they'll know that this person is *really* user *X*.

Clearly, the key you're providing now is the same one that `user2` gave them some time ago, and which they have stored in their giant table.  (Whether they've stored both `user2` *and* you, I have no idea, but their lookup finds only `user2` until `user2` removes that key.  If `user2` removes his key and they suddenly start finding you, that tells us that their giant table does in fact have both entries now—an interesting bit of proof, possibly useful in some future GitHub attack vector, but not really useful for anything immediate.)

(If you use https to connect to GitHub, none of this applies at all—it's all specific to ssh.)

Comment: ssh keys were where the problem was: I had not used ssh-add on my new 'user1' key so for a reason I don't quite get, there was no error, just a misidentify for 'user2'. Both are now present and ssh -T identifies correctly for each Host. Push now works fine

Comment: `ssh-add` sticks a key into the ssh agent.  ssh itself uses the keys from the agent instead of the keys from the file, if the agent is present and has keys.  Hence the problem will reappear (because the key in the key *file* is the same as that of user2) if the agent is not around or is not providing the updated key. You might want to either remove the wrong key-file entirely, or replace it with a correct one. Which to do depends on your security situation.